# Torch nngraph building nodes with nn.Linear

Tags: lua, torch

Hi I am new in torch/lua and I am doing the [practical5](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/nando.defreitas/machinelearning/practicals/practical5.pdf) of the oxford machine learning course:

What I am trying to implement is a simple layer:
m = x1 + x2 cmul linear(x3)
where cmul is the element multiply and linear is just a linear layer.

My code looks like:

```
-- params for the linear layer
params = {
    x3_size1 = 10,
    x3_size2 = 30
}
-- dummy nodes to take input data as nodes in graph
x1 = nn.Identity()()
x2 = nn.Identity()()
x3 = nn.Identity()()

-- modeling output = x1 + x2 cmul linear(x3)
l3 = nn.Linear(params.x3_size1, params.x3_size2)(x1)
m23 = nn.CMulTable()({x2,l3})
add = nn.CAddTable()({x1, m23})

-- specify the inputs and outputs of the graph
m = nn.gModule({x1,x2,x3}, {add})

graph.dot(mlp.fg, "mlp")
```

However, I got the error message:

```
  /Users/yiranzhang/torch/install/bin/luajit: /Users/yiranzhang/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Linear.lua:36: attempt to index local 'input' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    /Users/yiranzhang/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Linear.lua:36: in function 'forward'
    /Users/yiranzhang/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Module.lua:232: in function </Users/yiranzhang/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Module.lua:231>
    [C]: at 0x0156d0d0
    practical5.lua:32: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...hang/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:131: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x01013242e0
```

And if I only want
aa = nn.Linear(10,20)()

I got same error as above.

Even if I follow the [example](https://github.com/torch/nngraph/#two-hidden-layers-mlp) on the torch github:

I got the same error.

**UPDATE** and SOLVED:

I miss import the package. Although `nngraph` and `nn` are both referred to as `nn` in the code, they are actually different packages.

Should do

```
require 'nngraph'
```

And I only did

```
require 'nn'
```

Comment: Have you referred this [link](https://github.com/oxford-cs-ml-2015/practical5)

Comment: good point and thanks @MarmiK

Comment: welcome, also we can find there other practicals too :)

Answer (score 0):

Last argument in this line should be x3 instead of x1:

```
l3 = nn.Linear(params.x3_size1, params.x3_size2)(x3)
```